# I couldnt clear my image view after the animation

Tags: java, android

I couldn't make the image disappear or clear it from the activity

launcher activity:-
logo is a imageview declared

```
 Animation img = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.fade);
logo.startAnimation(img);
if(logo.getImageAlpha()==0.1) {
    logo.setImageDrawable(null);
}
```

fade.xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    >
<alpha
    android:duration="4000"
    android:fromAlpha="1.0"
    android:toAlpha="0.0"/>

</set>
```

I thought the image view will be cleared but it didn't.
I want some way to make the image view disappear at the end of the animation

Comment: set image visibility to gone after your animation completes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tried, but i think it may work. Try this:

```
Animation img = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.fade); //no need to use getApplicationContext I think
logo.startAnimation(img);

img.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener(){
@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
}           
@Override
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
}           
@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
   //try to clear the image here
   logo.setImageDrawable(null);

   //or you can make the imageview to invisible
   logo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
});
```

Comment: I have a doubt does the if condition work just after the animation started causing it to return false

Comment: @gokuladethya It might not work. It needs some time. You can use one Handler with some post delayed

Answer (score 0):

I assume logo is your imageView. So After checking end of animation, use this code to clear you image view:

```
logo.setImageResource(0);
```

or

```
logo..setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
```

Try this, I think would help.